# appendChild is not working, firefox on mac

Tags: javascript, svg

```js
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var arrivedV;
var arrivedNV;
var count = 0;

var timerFunction = null;

var svgElement = document.getElementById("van");
svgElement.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);

function mouseDown(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var coords = "X : " + x + ", Y : " + y;
  document.getElementById("mpost").value = coords;
  addtruck(x, y);
}

function addtruck(x, y) {
  var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rectangle");
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", 20);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", 20);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "#800000");
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "none");

  document.getElementById("svpg").appendChild(rect);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svpg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="934" height="502" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" onmousedown="mouseDown(e);">

  <image id="van" xlink:href="/uploads/2/1/7/6/21767914/4792239_orig.png" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" />

  <rect id="seabus1" x="445" y="320" width="5" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" transform="rotate(36 445 320)" />

  <rect id="seabus2" x="590" y="130" width="5" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" transform="rotate(36 590 130)" />
  <rect id="tank1" x="50" y="180" width="20" height="5" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);" transform="rotate(10 50 180)" />
  <rect id="tank2" x="40" y="280" width="20" height="5" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0); transform = " rotate(7 50 180) "" />
  <rect id="cargo1" x="498" y="296" width="20" height="5" style="fill:rgb(165,42,42);" transform="rotate(27 498 296)" />
</svg>

<input type="text" id="mpost" value="">
```

I am trying to add a rectangle from the position of the mouse.

I have tried a lot of other solution from online help but still no luck. i have tried to append to the img as well with no success. Based on what i see online this should work but i don't see what i am missing.
I am using Firefox.

Comment: Open your Javascript console. `onmousedown="mousedown(e)` is getting an error because the variable `e` isn't defined.

Comment: the code works after creating the attribute for the rectangle. you are right i get an error in the console but i can read the e.x and e.y in the textbox, weird, why?

Comment: When the handler is called from jQuery, it passes the event argument. Why are you inconsistent, using `onclick` for one element and jQuery for the other?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error from `onmousedown="mousedown(e)"`, because there's no variable `e`. The name of the global variable that contains the current event when you use an inline handler is `event`, so it should be `onmousedown="mousedown(e)"`.

Alternatively, you can use

```
document.getElementById("svpg").addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
```

I'm not sure if you really need to have `mousedown` handlers on both the `<svg>` and the `<image>`.

```js
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var arrivedV;
var arrivedNV;
var count = 0;

var timerFunction = null;

var svgElement = document.getElementById("van");
svgElement.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);

function mouseDown(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var coords = "X : " + x + ", Y : " + y;
  document.getElementById("mpost").value = coords;
  addtruck(x, y);
}

function addtruck(x, y) {
  var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rectangle");
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", 20);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", 20);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "#800000");
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "none");

  document.getElementById("svpg").appendChild(rect);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svpg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="934" height="502" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" onmousedown="mouseDown(event);">

  <image id="van" xlink:href="/uploads/2/1/7/6/21767914/4792239_orig.png" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" />

  <rect id="seabus1" x="445" y="320" width="5" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" transform="rotate(36 445 320)" />

  <rect id="seabus2" x="590" y="130" width="5" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" transform="rotate(36 590 130)" />
  <rect id="tank1" x="50" y="180" width="20" height="5" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);" transform="rotate(10 50 180)" />
  <rect id="tank2" x="40" y="280" width="20" height="5" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0); transform = " rotate(7 50 180) "" />
  <rect id="cargo1" x="498" y="296" width="20" height="5" style="fill:rgb(165,42,42);" transform="rotate(27 498 296)" />
</svg>

<input type="text" id="mpost" value="">
```

Comment: ok i added "event", so the console does not show me any error,gave me the x,y anyway, but the appendChild(rect) is nowhere to be seen. where is the mistake?

Comment: with the event this is what Jfiddle said:"Good work! Your JavaScript code is perfectly valid."... but not working

Comment: i wrapped a <g> around each object. problem is the they all stop in the same time.duh. I stopped working on it for now.